# Extremely slow performance with multiple user controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I've put together a scheduling application similar in style to that found in outlook, however it can show the schedules of multiple people. I have written a user control, basically a Border with gradient filled background & TextBlock. One of these controls are added to a Canvas at a set location for every appointment. The trouble is, I will have multiple users, with multiple appointments and may need to display 1000 or so appointments at a time. Initially, it takes an absolute age to instantiate all of these objects, however, I can live with this.

Unfortunately, the big problem arises when I try to scroll through the appointments. I have a couple of buttons to scroll left and right and upon clicking these, the UserControls' Left position are moved left or right a certain number of pixels - it can take several seconds between clicking a button and repainting(I also tried with labels just to test, but it was the same).

I guess the real question here is how to implement an interface, showing hundreds of controls with adequate performance and if this isn't achievable, how would I approach such an UI.

Comment: I'm assuming the user can't look at 1000's of these events at a time, why not just load what the user can see? This is a feature of Virtualizing stack panels (used in lists): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or (as an alternative) just manually paint (render) the appointments in a single control. There's tons of examples for wpf about this topic. It gets harder when you want to interact with all of them but also doable.
Hint: A starting point would be WPF's [OnRender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is a TextBlock CustomControl. You can get the exact same style as you have in your usercontrol but with a somewhat faster loading time.

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it will be difficult if not impossible to completely understand the performance problem you are having, never mind provide a solution.

That said, from your description it sounds like you are really looking to present the user with some type of `ItemsControl`, such as `ListBox` or `ListView` (a specialization of `ListBox`). In an `ItemsControl`, you can specify an `ItemTemplate` that defines how each item in the list will appear; this is analogous to the `UserControl` you apparently are using now.

I believe it's likely it will work fine just with that change alone. I.e. define your per-item visual as a `DataTemplate` instead of a `UserControl`, and set the `ItemTemplate` property of e.g. your `ListBox` to that template, then just bind your collection of appointment objects to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property.

Note that the `ListBox` class already defaults to using `VirtualizingStackPanel` in its `ItemsPanel` template. So you should have no performance problems at all with this approach if you use `ListBox`.

If you want to use a different `ItemsControl` or create a custom one, you may or may not find that you need to use a virtualizing panel object explicitly (such as the `VirtualizingStackPanel` that `ListBox` uses). With just 1000 items in the list, even a non-virtualized panel may be fine, but if not then even when not using `ListBox`, you can always specify it explicitly.